# JavaScript fixed array or object length?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jvectormap

I need a way to store **two** values only within an array or object and limit its length to two values. The reason is that I am using a [jQuery Vectormap](http://jvectormap.com/) to calculate the distance and a draw line between two coordinates **x1/y1 & x2/y2**.

Whenever a region/country is clicked, corresponding markers are loaded and added to the map

```
 map.addMarker(id ,{latLng: [val.lat, val.long], name:val.name}) ; ect///
```

Now, whenever a marker is clicked I should be able to track count of two markers's selection and store their coordinates in an array then do the calculations..

```
onMarkerClick:function(e, code){
 var coordinates = map.markers[code].config.latLng;
 // latitude = coordinates[0]
// longitude = coordinates[1]
}
```

So if I were to use `myArray.push([coordinates[0],coordinates[1]])` for each marker clicked then I end up with countless number of coordinates and thus making it impossible to draw my line..

Is there a way to set myArray length to 2 then when I push more values overwrite the existing one?

Thanks

Comment: There's no built-in way to do that in JavaScript, but you can truncate an array simply by setting the `.length` to 2.

Comment: Just initialize the array to an empty array or set `.length` to zero before pushing the values in.  That will clear any previous values and you will only have the new values.

Comment: If(myArray.length >2){ myArray.length = 0 } ?

Comment: Thank you guys, I will do as advised.. truncate the array after a certain length limit and remove selected markers, then restart the process..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be fancy about it, you can create your custom class that does this...

```
function CappedArray(Size)
{
    this.push = function(Value) {
        if(this.length==Size)
        {
            this.shift();
        }
        CappedArray.prototype.push.call(this, Value);
    }
}

CappedArray.prototype = new Array();

//How you use it
var SomeArray = new CappedArray(2);
SomeArray.push([coordinates[0],coordinates[1]]);
...
```

Alternatively, if you want to force the fact that points should only be associated in successive pairs of insertions:

```
function PairArray()
{
    this.push = function(Value) {
        if(this.length==2)
        {
            this.splice(0, 2);
        }
        PairArray.prototype.push.call(this, Value);
    }
}

PairArray.prototype = new Array();

//How you use it
var SomeArray = new PairArray();
SomeArray.push([coordinates[0],coordinates[1]]);
```

Comment: Thanks. but I noticed that this resolves part of my prob :/ when the array limit is reach pushing new values would not overwrite existing ones.. not sure if it's possible. but thanks good to learn how to limit the length

Comment: In the above case, the oldest value will get shifted out (removed from the array) when the array is full and you push.

What would be the desired behavior when you push a new value and the array is full? The push fails?

Comment: I may not have been clear explaining, but imagine having 50 points on a map, whenever one is clicked the above function returns its coordinates,i wish to draw a line between two airports and calculate air distance, so i am kinda lost tracking clicks, when u click on point1->store coord, then point2 the same -> Draw line/distance, if user clicks on point 3? then i might need to do as jfriend&Pointy advised.. clear array then clear points and re-draw. Sorry I'm just brainstorming over here :)

Comment: With the above class, suppose that there are 4 points.
User click on point 1: [Point1]
User click on point 2: [Point1, Point2], line from point 1 to point 2
User click on point 3: [Point2, Point3], line from point 2 to point 3
User click on point 4: [Point3, Point4], line from point 3 to point 4

Comment: There, I fixed it to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object like this:

```
var coords = 
{
  "c1": [x1,y1],
  "c2": [x2,y2]
}
```

then when adding coordinates you could:

```
coords.c1 = coordinates[0]; 
coords.c2 = coordinates[1];
```